# NDDE: DDE Execute command becomes gibberish by the time it reaches the server

Tags: c#, interop, dde, ndde

I need to access a legacy application through DDE. I don't have debug access to this legacy application so it's pretty much a black box to me.

However, I do know it works because I have some VBA code that communicates with the application through DDE without issue. The first few lines in the VBA code basically looks like this.

```
lngDDEChannel = DDEInitiate(App:="LEGAPP", Topic:="DDECONV")
DDEExceute channel:=lngDDEChannel, Command:="START_SESSION_12345"
strInfo$ = DDERequest(channel:=lngDDEChannel, Item:="INFO_FIELD")
```

*N.B. The actual names and commands are different from what is shown here. The number of characters in the command is equal to the ones of the original command, though. Only characters that can be represented in ASCII.*

As mentioned, this code works perfectly fine. As a side note, DDERequest will only provide data after the DDExecute command was executed. If not, it will return empty buffers.

I'm trying to port this code to C#. Since Microsoft didn't implement DDE in DotNet, I decided to go with the open source library [NDDE](https://github.com/anphonic/NDde).

This is how I've rewritten the code fragment above:

```
using (var client = new DdeClient("LEGAPP", "DDECONV")
{
    client.Connect();
    client.Execute("START_SESSION_12345");
    strVar = client.Request("INFO_FIELD");
}
```

A connection between the client and the server is established, I checked that. Unfortunately, the server doesn't understand the execute command. Instead of the command "START_SESSION_12345", it seems to receive some gibberish.

[image: Error message legacy app]

My initial thought was that there must be an issue with the string encoding. Strings in VBA are 7-bit ANSI strings while strings in DotNet are 16-bit. However, NDDE seems to be smarter than that, using a connection context, a specific encoding for all data exchanged with the DDE server can be set. The default is ASCII which actually should be the right choice here since all the characters in the command string can be represented in ASCII. Nevertheless, I tried playing with the context encoding with all possible values, such as UTF-7, UTF-8, ANSI, ASCII, UTF-16 (little and big endian). No matter what I try, I keep receiving gibberish, it's just slightly different gibberish which proves that the encoding is really taken into account.

I looked at the source of NDDE. The relevant lines are in the source file DdemlClient.cs.

```
var data = _Context.Encoding.GetBytes(command + "\0");
//Send the command to the server.
int returnFlags = 0;
var result = Ddeml.DdeClientTransaction(
                data,
                data.Length,
                _ConversationHandle,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Ddeml.CF_TEXT,
                Ddeml.XTYP_EXECUTE,
                timeout,
                ref returnFlags);
```

The function DDEClientTransaction is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddeclienttransaction). NDDE invokes the function in 2 ways:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DdeClientTransaction", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr DdeClientTransaction(IntPtr pData, int cbData, IntPtr hConv, IntPtr hszItem, int wFmt, int wType, int dwTimeout, ref int pdwResult);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "DdeClientTransaction", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr DdeClientTransaction(byte[] pData, int cbData, IntPtr hConv, IntPtr hszItem, int wFmt, int wType, int dwTimeout, ref int pdwResult);
```

The code in my example is using the second pinvoke declaration but I also tried it using the first one, no difference.

I'm stuck. Since the DDE conversation through VBA works just fine, I have to assume that there is not a general problem with the DDE server. I have no idea why this isn't working.

EDIT

I've done some tests just to clarify for myself what kind of data is being transmitted. For the purposes of this test, I changed the execute command simply to "ABCD".

Encoding.Default (=ANSI Codepage) creates the following byte array:

[image: Byte Array ANSI]

The application receives this as command:

[image: ANSI error]

Encoding.ASCII creates the following byte array:

[image: Byte Array ASCII]

The application receives this as command:

[image: ASCII Error]

Encoding.Unicode (i.e. UTF-16) creates the following byte array:

[image: Byte Array Unicode UTF-16]

The application receives this as command:

[image: Unicode Error]

Maybe this will give someone smarter than me the right idea what's wrong.

Comment: That's what happens when an 8-bit encoded string gets interpreted as a 16-bit encoded string.  This library looks pretty flawed, its pinvoke declarations all use CharSet.Ansi and the DdeClientTransaction() call uses the wrong format type (should be 0).  Well, it is open source, you're lucky.

Comment: @HansPassant I did notice the wrong format type and I changed this manually and recompiled the library but this had no effect. In general, I checked if any issues were ever reported on this and I couldn't find a hit which indicates that most users of the library seem satisfied. Do you believe then it could be a flawed pinvoke declaration? How would you change it? I will add the current declaration to my question for reference. My own experience with interop is limited to say the least.

Comment: I also just compared the signature in NDDE with the one provided by http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/DdeClientTransaction.html. The only difference is that the latter does not describe an EntryPoint or a Charset in the import instruction.

Comment: Adding another declaration, say DdeClientTransctionW and now using CharSet.Unicode, would be the thing to try.

Comment: I did that. I even tried various charsets, from Unicode to Auto to None, nothing changed. It clearly is a case of character encoding problem but what's causing it, I still don't get.. I'm doing more tests.

Comment: Would be great if you could have a look at the edit I made to my question. What I'm noticing is that using ASCII or ANSI decoding, 4 characters with 4 bytes are transmitted as well as received. I'm also noticing that ASCII and ANSI have the same result which I guess is correct. When using Unicode, only 2 characters seem to be received by the application. Funny enough, those 2 characters are the same ones present at the beginning of the ASCII buffer. But I don't really have a conclusion for all this.